# SailsJs Models long integer support with postgresql

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

I'm having issues with a Sails application running with a PostgreSQL database. I needed to insert an 11 digits integer, but I can't find a simple way to tweak my models for this.

**Edit 1** 
here is an example of a model :

```
/**
 * Phone.js
 *
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
 */

module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        number: {
            type: 'integer',
            required: true,
            minLength: 9
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a way (using the ORM) to change that integer into a BIGINT in Postgre so I don't get `ERROR: integer out of rage` when inserting?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8sD0Xwv4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this, yo should just be able to define "bigint" as the type

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L241

also supports float, real, smallint ect . . .

Comment: Canonical link as file keeps changing :)

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/blob/f0c92f5d2ca6d654d520034c90a90562e3b5fb6c/lib/utils.js#L225

Answer (score 1):

Defining type as bigint didn't work in my case. I was getting an error in validation while creating an entry in the model.

However, I gave the following properties,

```
type: string,
numeric: true,
minLength: 10
```

It was good enough but not exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your value is returned as a string is because [PostgreSQL's maximum value for BIGINT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) (2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807) is considerably bigger than Javascript's [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (2^53 - 1 = 9007199254740991) so if Sails / Waterline ORM were to cast your returned value as an integer all the time there is a possibility of breaking things.

So, it's safer to return a string every time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by setting the attributes with the following:

```
type: 'ref',
columnType: 'int8',
```